# How to disable Firebase Analytics Automatic Events Only

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

We have been using Firebase Analytics to track custom events that we have in our app.

We noticed that some events are logged by Firebase Automatically that are mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069?hl=en).

And real frustration is that wherever I'm searching, It's showing we can either Have Auto Events + Custom events tracking **OR** no tracking at all.

Is there any possibility for Android OS how we can only get Custom events without Automatic events?

Comment: How did you work around this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I disabled automatic events by following the [firebase instruction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#disable_screenview_tracking)

Comment: The firebase instruction that you've referenced only disable the "screen_view" automatic event, it does not disable the [rest of the automatic events collected](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?visit_id=637916737731032125-460687413&rd=1#)

Comment: You are right. My bad